# Pid from fork not 0 or less than 0 (minix)

Tags: c, move, execvp, minix

I'm writting a C program in which I need some directory to be copied in the middle of the code. So I wrote this function, where I try to use fork and then execvp. However this code doesn't seem to enter pid==0, and is not less than 0 aswell. What can be wrong? I'm using minix if that matters

```
    void execCopy() {
    printf("I'm in execCopy\n");
    printf("ERROR 0: %s\n",strerror(errno));


    int pid = fork();

    if(pid < 0) {
        printf ("fork failed with error code= %d\n", pid);
        fprintf(stderr,"FORK error\n");
    }

    printf("ERROR 1: %s\n",strerror(errno));

    char *execArgs[] = { "cpdir", "-R", copy_path,paste_path, NULL };

    printf("Copy from %s to %s\n",copy_path,paste_path);

    if(pid == 0) {

        printf("I'm gonna exec\n");
        execvp("cpdir", execArgs);
        printf("I should never get here \n");

    }

    else {
        printf("I'm the father, going to return\n");
        printf("ERROR 2: %s\n",strerror(errno));

        return;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Dec 26 20:34:11 192 kernel: I'm in execCopy
Dec 26 20:34:11 192 kernel: ERROR 0: Not a directory
Dec 26 20:34:11 192 kernel: ERROR 1: Not a directory
Dec 26 20:34:11 192 kernel: Copy from /./home to /./home/lcom
Dec 26 20:34:11 192 kernel: I'm the father, going to return
Dec 26 20:34:11 192 kernel: ERROR 2: Not a directory
```

Comment: Why you are calling strerror(errno) without letting change the value of errno

Comment: That `errno` is already set to `ENOTDIR` as soon as you *enter* this doesn't bode well from the outset.

Comment: Have you tried to `printf("PID: %d\n", pid);`? Especially note the use of `\n` which outputs the line just assembled. Thus would lead to a better readable output *and* to output at all without `fflush()`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I know, but I honestly have no idea where that comes from. BUt could it be related to this problem in particular? thanks for your help

Comment: @glglgl Hi, the pid was 756 and once again I couldn't see any output from the child. Thanks for your help

Comment: @sas not sure if I understood what you asked, but if it was why I called sterror in the beginning of the function it was because I suspected the error came from before, as it turned out to be the case

Answer (score 2):

output buffering might be swallowing the child process output.  Try to `fflush(stdout)` before the exec.

Edit: after the fork, you should see two ERROR 1 and two Copy from lines.  You're not seeing any of the child process output.

Comment: I tried to flush before the "printf("I'm gonna exec\n");" as you explained but I'm still not seeing any output...Did I misunderstand where to write that line? Also is there any way to verify if the exec is executing correctly? Because no copy is being made whatsoever. Thanks for the effort

Comment: Also using \n in the end of each print should do the job, not needing to flush, am I correct? I added \n at the end of each printf and still getting only 1 process after fork

Comment: try the fflush right after the "Copy from" printf (and before the pid == 0 if).  Yes, stdout is traditionally line buffered, but minix might be different.  To check whether the fork itself worked, insert a `write(1, "forked\n", 7)` right after the fork.  It should print twice (parent + child).